# Full sized links as block in indented nested unordered list?

Tags: html, css, list, hyperlink, nested

I have a nested list with links in it. Unfortunately I cannot change the HTML structure, because the HTML is generated as it is.

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Link Level 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Nested Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Nested Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Nested Link</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## Layout

I have to indent the nested lists and I'm doing this with a `margin-left` on the nested lists like:

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
}
ul li ul {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

## Issue

The parent `li` gets resized because of the nested list's height, but the link of the `li` has the height of one line only. The link is not sized as large as the `li` / fully clickable.

I'm not able to make the link the size of the parent `li` and be clickable.
I was thinking of something like:

```
ul li a {
    min-height: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block; /* or inline-block */
    /* z-index has no effect on this */
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/sitemapul.png/

**Please review the sample more more details on the code.**

## Sample

You can find a simple working sample and the not working sample with nested lists here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dc6wS/3/

Answer (score 1):

Only solution i can think of is with jQuery / javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dc6wS/7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Dc6wS/8/

Comment: I want the first-level `li a` to have the size of the first-level `li`. The second-level lists can have different amount of items, so fixed heights won't help. -- A general `line-height` of 1.7em makes no sense at all and does not solve the problem. -- Feel free to test you solution in the sample code.

Comment: It's kind of a dump of the navigation structure and should be the sitemap. Therefore I want the nested elements to be clearly visible as child of the first-level category. -- I understand your edited solution, but this is still not the desired solution. -- I first `li`having the height of the second `ul` is **correct**, but the `li a` should have the same height.

Comment: Then explain your issue further. Else I can't help.

Comment: Why the hell would you want interactive empty space?

Comment: It's not 'empty' it's like a button. Think of Windows 8 styled tiles. -- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/sitemapul.png/